# Need to add code to return empty array as null

Tags: arrays, testing

This code will return an error if the array list is empty. I need the code to add to avoid the error and return null if it is empty. Thanks

```
public Comment findMostHelpfulComment()
{
    Iterator<Comment> it = comments.iterator();
    Comment best = it.next();
    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        Comment current = it.next();
        if(current.getVoteCount() > best.getVoteCount()) {
            best = current;
        }
    }

return best;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this is not the type of questions we expect on SO. Read [ask] to learn how we expect answers to be.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Comment findMostHelpfulComment()
{
    if (comments.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    // rest of method
}
```

Or you can start with a `null` best comment if you rework the loop a bit.

```
public Comment findMostHelpfulComment()
{
    Comment best = null;

    for (Comment current: comments) {
        if (best == null || current.getVoteCount() > best.getVoteCount()) {
            best = current;
        }
    }

    return best;
}
```

Comment: Omg... I swear I tried this. Thanks, it works now. God I feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Comment findMostHelpfulComment()
{
    Iterator<Comment> it = comments.iterator();
    Comment best = new Comment();
    best.setVoteCount(0);
    while(it.hasNext()) 
    {
        Comment current = it.next();
        if(current.getVoteCount() > best.getVoteCount()) {
            best = current;
        }
    }
    return best;
}
```

Try this. It won't have problem with empty array, but it will return a dummy `Comment` with `voteCount` set to `0`;